# Can you make a javascript regex that fails instead of passing when a match is found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

For example, can I make a regex so that the string passes if it does *not* contain "foo"?

What I'm doing is using nodejs express to match URLs. How do I match any URL that does *not* contain "foo"?

For example, the following matches the root page:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

But how can I do the same to match routes except for `/login`?

```
app.get(/regex_here/, function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

What should be the value of `regex_here` to match all pages except `/login`?

Comment: Does Express check the urls one by one? You could catch a specific case first then a general case (Not sure tho)

Comment: @nhahtdh I've updated my question. What does `/^(?!.*foo).*$/` mean exactly?

Answer (score 3):

[**From the documentation**](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB), it seems like you **must use** regular expressions.

So you will need to go with [**nhahtdh's pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542389/can-you-make-a-javascript-regex-that-fails-instead-of-passing-when-a-match-is-fo/13550600#comment18545798_13542389):

```
/^(?!.*foo).*$/
```

---

> What does `/^(?!.*foo).*$/` mean exactly?

### Explanation

The parenthesized expression is called a negative lookahead, i.e. the pattern can only match when, `.*foo` *doesn't* follow *immediately  after* the current position, which is the start of the string, as denoted by `^`.

So, the pattern matches everything—`.*`, unless `foo` is found somewhere after the beginning, which is to say the same as:

```
The pattern matches everything unless `foo` occurs in the string somewhere.
```

Comment: +1. I deleted my answer since it doesn't have anything to do with whatever being asked.

Comment: As usual, the `.*$` part can be omitted

Comment: @Pumbaa80 That depends on how the library matches requests. If the entire URL needs to match, you do need the `.*$`

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, I had to copy and paste your name btw, I failed numerous times to spell it manually^^